# Hiding Clone Game Object with Tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got an error while trying hiding and showing a group of clone object with tag. the clone is dynamic(position). I have toggle to visible and visible some information text. Now I want to hide and unhide the game object with tag. ("windtag"). Also tryna hiding those gameobject in arrow method.

```
public GameObject[] test;


public void invisible(bool log)
    {


        test= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("windtag");
        test.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = log;

    }
 
public void clone()
    {
        Canvas newcanvas = Instantiate(canvas);
        //Use .SetParent(canvasName,false)    
        Text cloneposition = Instantiate(shiposition, newpos);
        Text clonewind = Instantiate(windspeedtext, newpos);
        Text clonedlow = Instantiate(flowtext, newpos);
        Text clonetemperature = Instantiate(temperaturetext, newpos);
        newcanvas.transform.position = shipvalue.transform.position;
        cloneposition.transform.SetParent(newcanvas.transform, false);
        clonewind.transform.SetParent(newcanvas.transform, false);
        clonedlow.transform.SetParent(newcanvas.transform, false);
        clonetemperature.transform.SetParent(newcanvas.transform, false);
        clonewind.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        clonetemperature.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        
    }

 public void arrow(float[,] arrowdata)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < arrowdata.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < arrowdata.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                if (grid[x,y] ==1)
                {


                    if (arrowdata[x, y] == 5)
                    {
                        GameObject referenceArrow = Instantiate(Resources.Load("down")) as GameObject;
                        float posY = shipvalue.transform.position.y - 9f;
                        referenceArrow.transform.position = new Vector3(shipvalue.transform.position.x-0.5f, posY);
                    }
                    if (arrowdata[x, y] == 4)
                    {
                        GameObject referenceArrow = Instantiate(Resources.Load("top left")) as GameObject;
                        float posY = shipvalue.transform.position.y - 9f;
                        referenceArrow.transform.position = new Vector3(shipvalue.transform.position.x - 0.5f, posY);
                    }
                    if (arrowdata[x, y] == 3)
                    {
                        GameObject referenceArrow = Instantiate(Resources.Load("top right")) as GameObject;
                        float posY = shipvalue.transform.position.y - 9f;
                        referenceArrow.transform.position = new Vector3(shipvalue.transform.position.x - 0.5f, posY);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

this is the error :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'GameObject[]' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent' and no accessible extension method 'GetComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\Skylarking\Unity\My First Game\MyFirstGame\Assets\Scripts\test.cs  391 Active

Comment: `FindGameObjectsWithTag` returns an array `GameObject[]`! Either iterate that one or use the method for a **single** `GameObject` without the `s`: `FindGameObjectWithTag` ... looks typo-based

Answer (score 1):

I think your current problem is that there is more than one Object with the Tag "windtag". So if you search for GameObject with that tag more than one is returned. Resulting in a GameObject Array instead of one GameObject.

An easy fix could be to add different Tags to all GameObject and then giving that string to the function.

```
invisible(false, "tagexample1");

public void invisible(bool log, string tag)
{
    test= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(tag);

    test.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = log;
}
```

Or you could put your `GetComponent<Renderer>()` into a for loop. To hide/show all elements with the windtag. If that is what you want.

```
public void invisible(bool log)
{
    test= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("windtag");

    foreach (GameObject gm in test){
        gm.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = log;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the first solution it should be  `FindGameObjectWithTag` without the `s` in order to return a single reference instead of an array

Comment: If my solution was correct. I would appreciate it when you could mark it as a solution thanks :D

Comment: Done Mathew..  Your answer also helped me.. Thanks